# Combining 2 Collection in 1 Template Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm trying to make a category system and i cant seem to figure out how to make it work.
here's a mock js and html to demonstrate what im trying to accomplish

test.js

```
Categories = new Meteor.Collection('categories');
Rooms = new Meteor.Collection('rooms');

if (Meteor.isClient) {    
   Template.Category_System.categories = function () {
      return Categories.find({});
   };
   Template.Category_System.rooms = function () {
      return Rooms.find({}); //here i want to return the rooms and users in the Rooms collection but only the rooms that fall under the category and subcategory of the Categories collection
   };
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
   Meteor.startup(function () {
        Categories.insert({category:"category1",subcategories:[{subcategory:"subcategory1",rooms:[]},{subcategory:"subcategory2",rooms:[]}]};
        Categories.insert({category:"category2",subcategories:[{subcategory:"subcategory1",rooms:[]},{subcategory:"subcategory2",rooms:[]}]};

        Rooms.insert({category:"category1",subcategory:"subcategory1",room:'Room_01',users:[a,b,c]});
        Rooms.insert({category:"category1",subcategory:"subcategory1",room:'Room_02',users:[d,e,f,g,h]});
        Rooms.insert({category:"category1",subcategory:"subcategory2",room:'Room_03',users:[i]}); 
        Rooms.insert({category:"category2",subcategory:"subcategory1",room:'Room_01',users:[j,k]});
        Rooms.insert({category:"category2",subcategory:"subcategory2",room:'Room_02',users:[l,m,n]});
        Rooms.insert({category:"category2",subcategory:"subcategory2",room:'Room_03',users:[o,p,q,r]});               
   });
}
```

test.html -> just the template

```
<template name="Category_System">
   {{#each categories}}
        {{category}}
        {{#each subcategories}}
             {{subcategory}}
             {{#each rooms}}
                  {{room}}{{users}}
             {{/each}}
        {{/each}}
   {{/each}}
</template>
```

the outcome i'm trying to achieve

```
category1
    -subcategory1
         -Room_01 a,b,c
         -Room_02 d,e,f,g,h
    -subcategory2
         -Room_03 i
category2
    -subcategory1
         -Room_01 j,k
    -subcategory2
         -Room_02 l,m,n
         -Room_03 o,p,q,r
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your mock code, you could do something like the following:

**category.js**

```
Categories = new Meteor.Collection('categories');
Rooms = new Meteor.Collection('rooms');

if (Meteor.isClient) {    
    Template.Category_System.categories = function () {
        return Categories.find();
    };
    Template.Category_System.rooms = function ( cat ) {
        var _subcat = this.subcategory,
            _cat = cat;
        return Rooms.find({ category: _cat, subcategory: _subcat });
    };
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.startup(function () {
        if ( !Categories.find().count() ) {
            Categories.insert({category:"category1",subcategories:[{subcategory:"subcategory1",rooms:[]},{subcategory:"subcategory2",rooms:[]}]});
            Categories.insert({category:"category2",subcategories:[{subcategory:"subcategory1",rooms:[]},{subcategory:"subcategory2",rooms:[]}]});
        }
        if ( !Rooms.find().count() ) {
            Rooms.insert({category:"category1",subcategory:"subcategory1",room:'Room_01',users:["a","b","c"]});
            Rooms.insert({category:"category1",subcategory:"subcategory1",room:'Room_02',users:["d","e","f","g","h"]});
            Rooms.insert({category:"category1",subcategory:"subcategory2",room:'Room_03',users:["i"]});
            Rooms.insert({category:"category2",subcategory:"subcategory1",room:'Room_01',users:["j","k"]});
            Rooms.insert({category:"category2",subcategory:"subcategory2",room:'Room_02',users:["l","m","n"]});
            Rooms.insert({category:"category2",subcategory:"subcategory2",room:'Room_03',users:["o","p","q","r"]});
        }
    });
}
```

**category.html**

```
<head>
  <title>Category System Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> Category_System}}
</body>

<template name="Category_System">
    <ul>
        {{#each categories}}
        <li>
            {{category}}
            <ul>
                {{#each subcategories}}
                     <li>
                        {{subcategory}}
                        <ul>
                            {{#each rooms ../category }}
                                <li>{{room}} - {{users}}</li>
                            {{/each}}
                        </ul>
                     </li>
                {{/each}}
            </ul>
        </li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</template>
```

Key thing to note is the passing of `../category` in the block helper for `rooms` and the template helper for `rooms` which accepts the category parameter and also makes use of the current `subcategory` data context to filter the Room collection.

If you run this under Meteor 0.8.0, you should see the following output...
[image: sample output from code found above]

You could make this easier by completing the reference to the `rooms` array in each of your `Category` docs. Either do this through a UI or capture the insertId for each `Room` doc and update the appropriate `Category` doc as you seed.

By the way, you'll probably want to throw in a check when you are seeding your collections (see the code above)...otherwise, you'll wind up with lots and lots of records every time you make a change and the app restarts.

Comment: Sorry to get back to you so late, this works perfectly. ill look into completing references and yeah i forgot to add the check thanks for pointing that out. thanks again for all the help and quick reply